# android, java version comportable? on windows

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I new installed windows 10 to study android/flutter and the version were below:
android-studio-2022.1.1.19-windows , jdk-19_windows-x64_bin.msi, flutter src.

But when I build and run it after AVD running, error related to gradle looks shown with error code 0.
What is a best combination to java version, android-studio version??

When I updated java version, the android studio didn't run anymore W/ message showing it couldnt loading jvm.dll and set JAVA_HOME. Of course I set JAVA_HOME.

Setting android studio is too hard to me.

Comment: solved. Use previous version android-studio-2020.3.1.26-windows.exe.
It works without jdk, and it runs with inner jdk.
Newest android version looks to have some error related to gradle, java vesrion.

Comment: I'm happy that you were able to solve your problem yourself.  You should probably delete the question now as it is not going to be helpful to anyone else.  (And ... frankly ... the question as written is incomprehensible.)